# Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics

Tags: javascript, function

JSHint is throwing following warning:

> Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics.
>   This is about creating a google maps project. 
>   I didn't find this exact problem in stackoverflow.

Any idea how to fix this it?

```
// The error refers on this line:
marker.addListener('click', function() {

  // here is all the function: 
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfowindow);
  });
}
```

my gitHub Repo:
https://github.com/Heleni/Google_Maps

Comment: please add all of the code and make sure it is indented 4 times so that it is visible

Comment: I guess it is pointing to the fact that you are using `marker.addListener(` inside a function and `marker` is defined outside. Try using `this` instead. Also `.addEventListener` inside another `addEventListener` is a bad idea

Comment: where's the loop

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your help. i just post my gitHub Repo if you would like to see more clear where is the problem. I did declare the marker before this function because i need to use it again before the function

Comment: i use" this" as Rajesh said but didnt work, i think i did use it wrong, could you change my function the way you think it will work?

Comment: You might bind `this` and the first parameter with `marker.addListener('click', populateInfoWindow.bind(this, largeInfowindow));`

Comment: hi @Mina, i replace this:
 marker.addListener('click', function(){
               populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfowindow);
              });
with your suggest code:
  marker.addListener('click', populateInfoWindow.bind(this, largeInfowindow));
and it works! Thanks a lot!
Can i ask you something else, that maybe is easy for you but complicated for me?

Comment: @Mines if you wish to tag someone in comment, use *@* followed my name. That way, necessary person gets notification and this also prevents typos in name. :-p

Comment: in the same project there is a small issue with infowindow, which cant figure out, when i click the marker infowindow works fine as well as when i close it.
 The problem is when i reopen it that the wikipedia error pops up, which it shouldn't.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Mines, actually not.

Comment: thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @Rajesh hi again!just notice that what Nina suggest   marker.addListener('click', populateInfoWindow.bind(this, largeInfowindow));
works fine from the list but markers are broken. 
They cant display infoWindows any more.
Any help guys?
https://github.com/Heleni/Google_Maps/blob/master/script/app2W.js
What Project need is when click a title from the list an infowindow pops up but also when user clicks on the marker an infowindow to display